# How to prevent React admin's auth provider from requesting authorization on 400 Bad request?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have ordinary custom data provider with only urls changed, and I see no sense to bring it's code here. The problem is that on 400 HTTP status response, my data provide redirects to /login.

As for me it's quite inadequate behaviour, since 400 bad request is not a 401 unauthorized. The problem of 400 originates from API backend, and I see no reason to re-login the user. Is it possible to prevent that redirection?

Comment: This behavior is set in your Auth Provider: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AuthProviderWriting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `authProvider` inspects API errors in its `checkError` method, so your normally have the ability to decide when an error requires a logout (in that case, return a rejected Promise), and when the error should just trigger a notification (and in that case, return a resolved Promise).

For instance:

```
// in src/authProvider.js
export default {
    login: ({ username, password }) => { /* ... */ },
    checkError: (error) => {
        const status = error.status;
        if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
            localStorage.removeItem('auth');
            return Promise.reject();
        }
        // other error code (404, 500, etc): no need to log out
        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    // ...
};
```

More info at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AuthProviderWriting.html#checkerror

Comment: On 400 my checkError receives error=undefined and status is empty string, so I don't see the possibilty to tune here.

Comment: the the problem is in your dataProvider, which doesn't return an error with a status